# Spark.sql and sqlContext.sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have imported the below modules. I tried to load data from sqlCtx.read.format, I am getting **"IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':""** error, but it works well when I use spark.read.format. I am seeing same behavior when I am retrieving data from registered temptable/view. What can I add extra to use sqlCtx.sql instead of spark.sql?

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import odbc as pyodbc
import os
import sys
import re
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import time as time
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local")
conf.setAppName("AppName")
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
```

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use? Maybe it will help others to solve this problem.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I spent two hours of my life in this one, just to realize I did not need:

```
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
```

Just using `SQLContext.read.(...)`, solved this in my case.